How do I find the max value under a logical filter?
Context:
I am writing a script for a factory that tests audio quality. I have software that returns the transfer function values at 2K different frequencies. I've setup a VBA script in Excel to run the software and populate an Excel spreadsheet with the data. However, I then use Octave/MatLab to analyze the data and find the low and high frequencies where the transfer function "rolls off". Rather than calling Octave/MatLab to do this calculation, I'd like to learn how to do this in VBA/Excel; which will eliminate the need for the factory to install another software.

Question:
How do I make an Excel VBA macro look at a 2x2000 table and find the low frequency and the high frequency where the transfer function is above the reference value at 1 [KHz] minus 3 [dB].
Considering the function I made in Octave/MatLab, how do I do the following in Excel/VBA:

Find the index/value in the fist column closest to 1000 (actual value likely to be 999.98, but not guaranteed) (call it freqRef)
Store the adjacent value of the cell in the next column (call it tfRef)
Review all rows above freqRef for values in the second column that are below "thRef - 3" (i.e. find "Max Freq" for logical conditions "Freq < 1000 & TF < tfRef - 3")
Review all rows below freqRef for values in the second column that are below "thRef - 3" (i.e. find "Min Freq" for logical conditions "Freq > 1000 & TF < tfRef - 3")


History: Here's the code I wrote in Octave/MatLab. It takes advantage of logical index filters (logic array) so that FREQLOG is all frequencies that satisfy the condition TF(f) - TF@1[KHz] + 3 < 0 (all frequencies where the transfer function is below the reference threshold). I've been trying to write this in VBA, but I don't know how to do it where I keep the indices abstracted.
[~, IDX] = min( abs( FREQ - 1000 ) );
FREQLOG = FREQ(TF - TF(IDX) + 3 < 0);
FREQLO = max(FREQLOG(FREQLOG < 1000))
FREQHI = min(FREQLOG(FREQLOG > 1000))


Try rewriting your Octave code using loops, you would more easily be able to translate a simple loop (or two). If you validate that it gives the same answer in Octave first then you can be confident in your translation to VBA. That said, you could probably also use an array formula in Excel for this with or without using VBA, for example max(if(...))

It doesn't sound too bad to do in Excel, but it would be handy to have a bit of sample data to work on.

Well if you were to translate this step by step into an Excel array formula you would end up with something like this:
=LET(freq,A2:A11,
Tf,B2:B11,
idx,XMATCH(MIN(ABS(freq-1000)),ABS(freq-1000)),
freqlog,FILTER(freq,Tf<INDEX(Tf,idx)-3),
MAX(FILTER(freqlog,freqlog<INDEX(freq,idx))))

and
=LET(freq,A2:A11,
Tf,B2:B11,
idx,XMATCH(MIN(ABS(freq-1000)),ABS(freq-1000)),
freqlog,FILTER(freq,Tf<INDEX(Tf,idx)-3),
MIN(FILTER(freqlog,freqlog>INDEX(freq,idx))))

but it does remind me of the advice given by a yokel to a gentleman who had got lost in the countryside:
If I were you, sir, I wouldn't start from here



Actually I wouldn't do it that differently if starting from scratch - maybe use Xlookup to get F(1000) and TF(1000) rather than using IDX plus Index to get the values, then do both filters together.
=LET(freq,A2:A11,
Tf,B2:B11,
d_1000,ABS(freq-1000),
f_1000,XLOOKUP(MIN(d_1000),d_1000,freq),
Tf_1000,XLOOKUP(MIN(d_1000),d_1000,Tf),
MAX(FILTER(freq,(freq<f_1000)*(Tf<Tf_1000-3))))

